# Drawing pivot lines from daily timeframe into intraday timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have created some pivot lines in the daily timeframe but i need these lines to be visible in the intraday timeframe, especially in the 1m timeframe

update: I have finally managed to get the 1D-Levels down to 1m-Timeframe.
Now i am facing the issue that i am limited to `max_bars_back = 4999` the levels will not be plotted on 1m timeframe, even if the corresponding candles are visible, but are >5000-1m-bars away. How can i overcome this limitation and plot as many levels/lines, as visible bars on the 1m timeframe? I thought if i do request.security("D") then the daily bars are taken into account, so why do i get the limitation on 1m-bar-count?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Auto Lines", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 4999, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)

string GROUP_LOGIC = "Logic Settings"

lookback = input.int(2, "Pivot Lookback", group = GROUP_LOGIC)
percent = input.int(2, "Prozent", group = GROUP_LOGIC)

string GROUP_STYLE = "Style Settings"

bullishColor = input.color(color.green, "Bullish Color", group = GROUP_STYLE)
bearishColor = input.color(color.red, "Bearish Color", group = GROUP_STYLE)
neutralColor = input.color(color.white, "Neutral Color", group = GROUP_STYLE)


var float currentHigh = na
var float currentLow = na
var float currentHighTmp = na
var float currentLowTmp = na

ticker_D = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular)
//[pH, pL, h, l, last_day_close, bar_index_d, time_d]  = request.security(ticker_D, "D", [ta.highest(lookback),ta.lowest(lookback), high, low, close, bar_index, time], gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)

pH              = request.security(ticker_D, "D", ta.highest(lookback), gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
pL              = request.security(ticker_D, "D", ta.lowest(lookback), gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
h               = request.security(ticker_D, "D", high, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
l               = request.security(ticker_D, "D", low, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
last_day_close  = request.security(ticker_D, "D", close, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
bar_index_d     = request.security(ticker_D, "D", bar_index, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
time_d          = request.security(ticker_D, "D", time, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)

plot(bar_index_d, "bar_index_d", display = display.data_window)
plot(time_d, "time_d", display = display.data_window)
plot(currentHigh, "currentHigh", display = display.data_window)
plot(currentLow, "currentLow", display = display.data_window)

plot(h, "h", display = display.data_window)
plot(l, "l", display = display.data_window)

plot(pH, "pH", display = display.data_window)
plot(pL, "pL", display = display.data_window)

var int high_counter = 0
var int low_counter = 0
var int high_counter_2 = 0
var int low_counter_2 = 0

newSession = bool(ta.change(time('D')))
count = ta.barssince(newSession)


if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    for i = 0 to 4999
        if i == 0
            currentHigh := h
            currentLow := l
            high_counter := high_counter+1
            low_counter := low_counter+1
            
            if timeframe.isdaily
                line.new(x1=bar_index_d, x2=bar_index_d+1,y1=currentHigh,y2=currentHigh,xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = bullishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
                line.new(x1=bar_index_d, x2=bar_index_d+1,y1=currentLow,y2=currentLow,xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = bearishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
            if timeframe.isintraday
                line.new(x1=time[count + 1], x2=time_close + (1 * 86400000),y1=currentHigh,y2=currentHigh,xloc = xloc.bar_time,color = bullishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
                line.new(x1=time[count + 1], x2=time_close + (1 * 86400000),y1=currentLow,y2=currentLow,xloc = xloc.bar_time,color = bearishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)

        else
            if h[i] > currentHigh and h[i] == pH[i]
                high_counter_2 := high_counter_2+1

                if timeframe.isdaily
                    line.new(x1=bar_index_d-i, x2=bar_index_d-i+1,y1=h[i],y2=h[i],xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = h[i] > currentHigh * (1.00 + percent/100) ? neutralColor : bullishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
                if timeframe.isintraday
                    line.new(x1=time_d[count+i], x2=time_close + (1 * 86400000),y1=h[i],y2=h[i],xloc = xloc.bar_time,color = h[i] > currentHigh * (1.00 + percent/100) ? neutralColor : bullishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
                currentHigh := h[i]                
            if l[i] < currentLow and l[i] == pL[i]
                low_counter_2 := low_counter_2+1

                if timeframe.isdaily
                    line.new(x1=bar_index_d-i, x2=bar_index_d-i+1,y1=l[i],y2=l[i],xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = l[i] < currentLow * (1.00 - percent/100) ? neutralColor : bearishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
                if timeframe.isintraday
                    line.new(x1=time_d[count+i], x2=time_close + (1 * 86400000),y1=l[i],y2=l[i],xloc = xloc.bar_time,color = l[i] < currentLow * (1.00 - percent/100) ? neutralColor : bearishColor,width = 1,extend = extend.right)
                currentLow := l[i]
            //if l[i + 1] > h[i] and l[i + 1] > currentHigh and h[i] > currentHighTmp
                //drawLine(bar_index - i, h[i], bar_index - i + 1, h[i], h[i] > currentHigh * (1.00 + percent/100) ? neutralColor : bullishColor, "yes")
                //currentHigh := h[i]
                //drawLine(bar_index - i - 1, l[i + 1], bar_index - i, l[i + 1], l[i + 1] > currentHigh * (1.00 + percent/100) ? neutralColor : bullishColor, "yes")
                //currentHigh := l[i + 1]

            //if h[i + 1] < l[i] and h[i + 1] < currentLow and l[i] < currentLowTmp
                //drawLine(bar_index - i, l[i], bar_index - i + 1, l[i], l[i] < currentLow * (1.00 - percent/100) ? neutralColor : bearishColor, "yes")
                //currentLow := l[i]
                //drawLine(bar_index - i - 1, h[i + 1], bar_index - i, h[i + 1], h[i + 1] < currentLow * (1.00 - percent/100) ? neutralColor : bearishColor, "yes")
                //currentLow := h[i + 1]

            if l[i] < currentLow
                currentLowTmp := l[i]
            if h[i] > currentHigh
                currentHighTmp := h[i]
        if currentLow < currentLowTmp
            currentLowTmp := currentLow
        if currentHigh > currentHighTmp
            currentHighTmp := currentHigh

plot(high_counter, "high_counter", display = display.data_window)
plot(low_counter, "low_counter", display = display.data_window)
plot(high_counter_2, "high_counter_2", display = display.data_window)
plot(low_counter_2, "low_counter_2", display = display.data_window)
```

Comment: If i go into the lower timeframes, i get this error.

I don't need as much bars as plottet. Idea is to plot only 3-5x of ADR on top and 3-5xADR to bottom

https://snipboard.io/BUCkEF.jpg

Comment: Why is there a difference of the variable bar_index_d from day timeframe on different timeframes - as example comparison 4H and daily chart

https://snipboard.io/4pcm8a.jpg